# A compiling example of the hiding mentioned in the Note in [over.unary]/2

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

[[over.unary]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.unary#2)

> The unary and binary forms of the same operator are considered to have
>   the same name. [ Note: Consequently, a unary operator can hide a
>   binary operator from an enclosing scope, and vice versa. —end note ]

I'd like to see a compiling example of a snippet where this hiding occurs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A fairly simple example<sup>1</sup>:

```
struct foo {
    void operator+(foo const&) {}
};

struct bar : foo {
    void operator+() {}
};

int main() {
    bar a, b;
    a + b; // Can't add two bars
}
```

The name of the member function is `operator+`, so the one declared in `bar` hides the one in `foo` when we overload it. That makes the addition at the end of `main` ill-formed.

But if you had two `foo` objects (that are not `bar`), the addition would be perfectly okay.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Pardon me it's a non-compiling one, but usually the issue with name hiding is that it *prevents* programs from building all of a sudden.</sub>

Comment: To construct an example that still compiles, but selects a different overload, one could use a mixture of member and non-member overloads, where the member one is a better conversion (but hidden by inheritance)